# What exactly does the 'auto' value mean for the CSS height property?

Tags: html, css, height

w3schools says that for `height`:

> auto : The browser calculates the height. This is default

But what does “browser calculates the height” mean? Does it mean it just simply sums up the contained elements’ heights? Is this always calculated with the same method for all browser?

Comment: Although nothings wrong in this particular case, in general I'd advise you to stay away from w3schools.com.  Much of their information is [misleading or incorrect](http://w3fools.com) and they often promote poor practices.  [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is a great resource for web development.

Comment: YOu just reminded me an old practice I used to apply on google: "whatever-key-word MDN" will lust the MDN content search result at the top relevant to your needs. Like :".click MDN"

Comment: yeah, that's what I do whenever I need to quickly reference something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does it mean *browser calculates the height*?

It means the browser will make the element's height sufficient to fit its content.

> Does it mean it just simply sums up the contained elements heights if they are up on each other?

Nope, it is more complicated than that, but I'm sure that is part of it.

> Is this always calculated with the same method for all browsers?

No, there are generally small variances. You should calculate the element's height in JavaScript if you intend to perform calculations based on it, don't assume it will have the same height on all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

The CSS 2.1 spec, and the CSS3 Basic Box model spec, have sections on how browsers should calculate heights:

- [CSS 2.1, Section 10.6.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block)
- [CSS3 Basic Box Model, Section 9](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#Calculating)

I find it a bit difficult to translate them into what should actually happen though, and I couldn’t say if browsers actually follow these descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

It summs up: the contained elements, plus the paddings, border and margins.
The *method* for summing should be the same in all browsers, but the size of elements differ.

Comment: ... plus collapsed margins. It isn't a trivial calculation.

Comment: Isn't it minus collapsed margins? And it only worries about things in normal flow.