# Navbar swelling in height when navbar-logo is given custom styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was just trying my logo to look fancy and i did manage to make it look fancy(making it look oval, drop shadow , displaying only half the circle in view), [SEE HERE](http://purplefront.net/navbar_bug/banner.html), now the problem is the height of the navbar somehow seems to be controlled by the size of the `navbav-brand` img,  notice how the navbar has increase abnormally in size and for no apparent reason.

The increase in size occured after i added the following styles to `navbar-brand`:

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: auto;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-noscroll">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="http://www.techfume.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/logo.jpg" alt="TLC montessori Logo">
        </a>

      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#aboutus">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#programmes">programmes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#gallery">gallery</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#contactus">Contact us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

If you go to source in chrome and open banner.css and comment out line 77-84 , you'll see the navbar reach its normal size.

Also as i mentioned the img size of the logo seems to effect the size of the navar eg. if you change the size of the `img` to `10px`(ridiculous ! i know), The navbar will be back to its normal size.

So what is it causing my navbar to swell so rediculiously ? I mean can somebody point out the exact reason "WHY" ? i mean i want to know "WHY" this is happening , not just how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: give '#navbar-brand' and '#navbar-brand img' 100% height and give '.navbar-header' a height

Comment: @sasha i'am afraid that approach goes against responsive design !

Comment: It would help to put your styling on the image instead of the anchor. @sasha, answers go down there.

Comment: @Alexander Solonik: well it actually does not have to. my general approach: make your site's container width-responsive (using a grid system), BUT use fixed relative heights (e.g. 3em / 3rem) for your elements like images, navbars etc.. doing so your design would become much more predictable. use media queries to handle different screen sizes. p.s. most logos are not responsive in that way, that they adapt their size gradually to the screen size

Answer (score 0):

Just set `height: 100px;` to your .navbar. Additionally you should set `height: 100px; overflow: hidden;` to your .navbar-header, so that the shadow won't show above the image.
You may change the value for the height, so it fits to your needs.
If your `height` will be over 150px, you won't need to set `overflow: hidden;` to your navbar-header.

Comment: thanks , but does't answer the why , is neither the solution i want.

Comment: An img tag is a block element, so it will increase the size of its parent element. If the block element itself isn't bigger than the size of its parent, it won't increase it, that's why your navbar has it's regular size if you minify the img to 10px. If you don't want this effect, just make your navbar-brand `position: absolute;`.

Comment: i don't want position absolute and no neither is an `img` a block level element !

Comment: Your navbar-brand container is bigger than it's parent because you set it's `height` to `auto`, so it will increase it's size. That's just normal behaviour. Look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914327/what-exactly-does-the-auto-value-mean-for-the-css-height-property), maybe it becomes clearer.

Comment: i want the height , to stay Auto !